# emacs position of the first char in a word

Tags: emacs, elisp

Hi is there a function to get the first char position of a word
Like using backward-word but just to know the char position insted of going backward.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another answer (no better than @edwinallenz's answer):

```
(car (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'word))
```

Answer (score 2):

I found it

> (save-excursion (backward-word) (point))